# How to call instance in another method (main)

Tags: java

New programmer here:

I need help to be able to call an instance of the class Album from a method right above.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Album a1 = new Album("Fede Finn og Funnyboys", "Glade Aber");

        Ar1.addAlbum(a1);

    }

    public void runner1() {
        Ar1.sortList();
        System.out.println("");
        toTxt(1);
        Ar1.removeAlbum(Album.**a1**);
```

I get this mistake: a1 cannot be resolved or is not a field.

Easy problem - i know, sorry :)

Thx

Comment: Read about scopes and visibility.

Comment: You're calling a static property on `Album` called `a1`.  Is there a static property on `Album` called `a1`?  There's a variable of type `Album` called `a1` in `main()`, but that's not even close to the same thing.  And `main()` isn't calling `runner1()` anyway, so I'm not really sure what's going on here.

Comment: Let me try to explain then. 

If i delete "public void runner1(), so the methods below are run in main i have no mistake. The problem is I would like 2 different methods-series to be run, so i need it to be called from my main instead of actually being in the main.

Comment: Ar1 is another class. Its an arraylist (Arkiv (archieve))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`a1` scope is only inside main. This means you can use `a1` only in the main method. To be able to use it outside of main, you need to pass it as a parameter to the method you're going to use it in. So if you want to use `a1` in your `runner1` method (assuming runner1 is a method of the `Album` class, you need to do something like:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Album a1 = new Album("Fede Finn og Funnyboys", "Glade Aber");
        a1.runner1();//you need to call runner1 on the Album object

        Ar1.addAlbum(a1);

    }
```

After you call runner1 on the Album object `a1`, inside `runner1` you can refer to that object by the keyword `this`

EDIT:
The idea is the same here. You create your Album object in your main method, and call the method where the bottom part of your call exists. Inside this method refer to the Album object by `this`. For example if the method is called `runner1`, then:

```
public void runner1() {
        Ar1.sortList();
        System.out.println("");
        toTxt(1);
        Ar1.removeAlbum(this);//refer to the Album object you want to remove by this
}
```

So from your main method, each time you call the `runner1` method on an Album object, this object will be refered to as `this` and you can use the keyword in the `removeAlbum` method.

So in your main if you have three Album objects called `a1, a2, a3`, and you call the `runner1` method in this order:

```
a1.runner1();
a2.runner1();
a3.runner1();
```

Then each call will remove the object that calls the method because you refer to it by `this` in that method.

Hope this solves your issue

Comment: Can this be done in a way so I can call a1 from different runner methods without writing a new method for each?

Comment: What do you exactly mean by calling a1 from different runner? Try to provide an example of what you're trying to do.

Comment: look at this image (a shot of my code)
http://i.imgur.com/REQ5DQh.png
The lowest part where the series of methods start (Ar1.sortList()); - I want that in a method of its own, so i can make multiple of them with differences.

Comment: I've edited the answer. Hope this is the thing you're looking for

Comment: No problem and thanks for choosing the answer. You can also upvote the answer if you found it useful :-).

Answer (score 0):

Scope of a1 is inside main so if you try to use it outside main you will get error above you mentioned.

```
Album a1 = new Album("Fede Finn og Funnyboys", "Glade Aber");
public static void main(String[] args) {
     Ar1.addAlbum(a1);

}
```

Comment: @user2151525 create instance of Album outside main.

Comment: Doesn't a1 need to be static to be used inside main?

Answer (score 0):

main method is a diffrent method， you can`t call class filed in this method

if you want do that，here is code demo

```
class Albumdemo{
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Album a1 = new Album("Fede Finn og Funnyboys", "Glade Aber");
    Albumdemo Ar1 = new  Albumdemo（）；
    Ar1.addAlbum(a1);

}

public void runner1(Album a1) {
    Ar1.sortList();
    System.out.println("");
    toTxt(1);
    Ar1.removeAlbum(Album.**a1**);
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

a1 is locally scoped in the main method. If you assign the variable as a member instead, you'll be able to reference it:

```
public class Album {
    private static ArrayList<Album> Ar1 = new ArrayList<Album>(); // I assume you have one of these here?
    private static Album a1 = new Album("Fede Finn og Funnyboys", "Glade Aber");

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Ar1.addAlbum(a1);
        new Album().runner1();
    }

    public void runner1() {
        Ar1.sortList();
        System.out.println("");
        toTxt(1);
        Ar1.removeAlbum(a1);
    }
}
```